# data represetation in circle graph

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I have data represented in column basic chart using highcharts. Currently this column graph is working fine. now i want to do that in circular shape as it shows the comparison. Now the next graph which i am looking for is to show 6 circles showing two lines with their values and colors.
Here's the HTML code

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

and JS code:

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        for (var i = 0; i < this.series.data.length; i++) {
                            this.series.data[i].update({ color: '#ECB631' }, true, false);
                        }
                        this.update({ color: '#f00' }, true, false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [ {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3]

    }]
});
});
```

and here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shawson/CkkbF/8/

I just want it like this with two colors and values.

[image]

Any help? Any hint

Comment: you can use Donut chart here. check for it http://jsfiddle.net/bLaokfgt/

Comment: @strikers .. yeah i found lot stuff on donut chart but the problem is i need to compare both the values out of hundred.

Comment: how? Any link or hint?

Comment: can you please provide some sample data so that I can give a clear example